# Laravel foreach loop is multiplying the database entries with number of inputs

Tags: json, laravel, api, foreach

I am trying to save multiple app_users and team_members from one app_user_id. Everything is working perfectly but the app_user_number is saving same entry thrice i.e same entry for all app_users.
If I take the " appUsers->save(); " inside the third foreach loop then I end up getting 9 entries for three inputs i.e the entries are getting multiplied to the number of inputs but then the app_user_nummber is perfectly working. Please help me set a correct foreach loop so that the entries doesn't repeat.

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input', true));

$appUserId = $input->app_user_id;

$team = new Team();
$team->app_user_id = $appUserId;
$team->save();

foreach($input->users as $obj){

  foreach($obj->app_user_name as $appUserName){

    foreach($obj->app_user_number as $appUserNumber) {

      $appUser = new AppUser();
      $appUser->app_user_full_name = $appUserName;
      $appUser->app_user_mobile_number = $appUserNumber;
      $appUser->app_user_stage_name = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_designation_id = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_dob = '1000-01-01 00:00:00';
      $appUser->app_user_gender = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_year_experience = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_project_experience = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_genre_specialisation = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_languages_worked_in = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_project_expectation = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_skills = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_profile_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_aadhar_card_front_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_aadhar_card_back_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_industry_card_front_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_industry_card_back_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_company_card_front_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_company_card_back_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_left_shot_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_right_shot_photo_url = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_is_verified = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_rating = 0;
      $appUser->app_user_email_id = 0;
    }
    $appUser->save();
    $teamMembers = new TeamMembers();
    $teamMembers->team_id = $team->team_id;
    $teamMembers->app_user_id = $appUser->app_user_id;
    $teamMembers->save();
  }
}

$response = json_encode(array("response_code"=>200, "response_message"=>"Success"));
return $response;
```

Input json:

```
{
   "app_user_id" : "1",
   "users" : [{
     "app_user_name" : ["Harry", "Hodor", "Hillary"],
     "app_user_number" : ["2", "3", "4"]
   }]
}
```

Comment: You've tagged phpmyadmin, but it doesn't seem like your question has anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application, which is a graphical interface to allow administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database server. I've edited your post to remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve what you need, assuming the order of name matches the order of number, you only need to loop for either one, but get the $key so you can also access the other array:

```
foreach($input->users as $obj){
  foreach($obj->app_user_name as $key=>$appUserName){
      $appUser = new AppUser();
      $appUser->app_user_full_name = $appUserName;
      $appUser->app_user_mobile_number = $obj['app_user_number'][$key];
      $appUser->app_user_stage_name = 0;
      ...
      $appUser->app_user_email_id = 0;
      $appUser->save();
      $teamMembers = new TeamMembers();
      $teamMembers->team_id = $team->team_id;
      $teamMembers->app_user_id = $appUser->app_user_id;
      $teamMembers->save();
  }
}
```

a better approach might be to restructure your input array, it could become

```
   "users" : [{
     "app_user_name" : "Harry",
     "app_user_number" : 2
   },{
     "app_user_name" : "Hodor",
     "app_user_number" : 3
   },{
     "app_user_name" : "Hillary",
     "app_user_number" : 4
   }]
```

and you can loop it like so

```
foreach($input->users as $key=>$val){
  $appUser = new AppUser();
  $appUser->app_user_full_name = $val->app_user_name;
  $appUser->app_user_mobile_number = $val->app_user_number;
  $appUser->app_user_stage_name = 0;
```

Comment: The third solution works perfectly fine after changing the input Json. Thanks for you help man, sorry for replying late was busy with development work.